# Override project-level nuget settings with local user settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, nuget, nuget-package

I have a weird edge case where I have nuget configs in all my solutions i cant change, but some users will need to use different configs.

Project level always takes precedence from what I read. But how do I have a local user level nuget config override the solution level configs?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I have users where their nuget repo locations defined in the config have to be different due to network related stuff. But please dont dismiss this question and not answer it and challenge my use case instead

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Nuget can be configured at project level, then user, then computer. The best you could hop efor would be to exclude the project level config from source control and make users create their own.

Comment: hmm maybe i could just add additional sources? And nuget will just use the sources it can connect to? so i dont think i do need to override. Will that work?

Comment: Another alternative, if the configs are on different hosts, you could override the IP address in the hosts file.

Comment: @red888 Adding additional nuget source will work. I used to have a local Nuget cache directory as backup source when on different network. But this is also changed in v3 of Nuget manager.

Comment: changed as in wont work anymore?

Comment: You can't use the Nuget cache as backup as it already does that internally (I guess). You can keep a copy of your private Nuget package from Network to local drive and use that as additional source.